# Google Map not re-drawing after clicking a line

Tags: google-maps, redraw, lightbox2

My Google Map only shows up fine the first time. Clicking the line a second time or more, the map does not re-draw properly and so is unusable.

I am using the following code:

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.3820845337596, -1.46965489864111);
        var myOptions = {
          zoom: 15,
          center: myLatlng,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
          scrollwheel:false
        }
        
        var map     =   new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
        
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: myLatlng,
              map: map,
              title: 'we are right here ...'
         });
         
        var myLatlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(53.3820845337596, -1.46965489864111);

      marker.setMap(map);
      
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      });
      
      google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

With `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')` at the end being my attempt to get the map to behave correctly.

You can see the effect at http://test2omniforce.co.uk/node/8 and clicking on the map image.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like a width and height are set on your div with id 'map_canvas' in map.php. I wonder if this is causing the map to not render correctly?

Maybe try adding some dimensions and see if that works.

Good luck!

Comment: There is a width of 800px and a height of 500px set in CSS on div#map_canvas